# What's the difference between safe, regular and atomic registers?

Tags: language-agnostic, concurrency, terminology, atomic

Can anyone provide exhaustive explanation, please? I'm diving into concurrent programming and met those registers while trying to understand consensus.

[From Lamport's "On interprocess communication"](http://blog.cykerway.com/post/327): *...a regular register is atomic if two successive reads that overlap the same write cannot obtain the new then the old value...*.

Assume, that first comes `thread0.write(0)` - with no overlapping. Basically, one can say using Lamports definition that `thread1` can read first **1** and then **0** again, if both reads are consequent and overlap with `thread0.write(1)`. But how is that possible?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Reads and writes to a shared memory location take a finite period of time, so they may either overlap, or be completely distinct.

e.g.

```
Thread 1:      wwwww     wwwww
Thread 2:   rrrrr              rrrrr
Thread 3:   rrrrr rrrrr
```

The first read from thread 2 overlaps with the first write from thread 1, whilst the second read and second write do not overlap. In thread 3, both reads overlap the first write.

A **safe** register is only safe as far as reads that do not overlap writes. If a read does not overlap any writes then it must read the value written by the most recent write. Otherwise it may return any value that the register may hold. So, in thread 2, the second read must return the value written by the second write, but the first read can return any valid value.

A **regular** register adds the additional guarantee that if a read overlaps with a write then it will either read the old value or the new one, but multiple reads that overlap the write do not have to agree on which, and the value may appear to "flicker" back and forth. This means that two reads from the same thread (such as in thread 3 above) that both overlap the write may appear "out of order": the earlier read returning the new value, and the later returning the old value.

An **atomic** register guarantees that the reads and writes appears to happen at a single point in time. Readers that act at a point before that point will all read the old value and readers that act after that point will all read the new value. In particular, if two reads from the same thread overlap a write then the later read cannot return the old value if the earlier read returns the new one. Atomic registers are **linearizable**.

[The Art of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916) by Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit gives a good description, along with examples and use cases.

Comment: You should site Art of Multiprocessor Programming :)

Comment: @Anthony Why are regular registers considered to be quiescently consistent?

Comment: If there is a quiescent period where there are no accesses then all subsequent reads will read the same (consistent) value

Comment: In atomic registers: when the two reads overlaps the write operation the first read can return either the old or the new value?

Comment: Which page is the examples and use cases on>?

Comment: In my copy it's chapter 4: Foundations of Shared Memory