# Atomic Register Read Operation Return Value

Tags: concurrency, atomic

I want to know wich of these options is correct.

An atomic register R initially holding value 33 is used by two process P and Q that perform the
following concurrent operations: P executes write(R,68) during time interval [2,6] and Q executes
read(R) during time interval [4,7] (the operations overlap in time). In this situation, since the
register provides the atomic semantics, it is guaranteed that:

(A) The read operation always returns value 68.

(B) The read operation always returns value 33.

(C) The read operation can return either value 33 or value 68.

(D) Nothing can be ensured, because the operations are concurrent.

I know atomic registers ensure that

if Ri → Rj then i  j (if i is before j)

Comment: What is an "atomic register"? Never heard that term. Registers or memory locations are not atomic, operations on them are.

Comment: It's discussed plenty in http://www.amazon.com/The-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/dp/0123973376

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read an explanation here:
[What's the difference between safe, regular and atomic registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871633/whats-the-difference-between-safe-regular-and-atomic-registers)

The notable piece of information is

> Readers that act at a point before that point will all read the old value and readers that act after that point will all read the new value

So by definition, since the read occurs before the write completes it should always see `33`.  If it were a regular register, it could flicker between the two.

Comment: From definition of regular register: if two reads from the same thread overlap a write then the later read cannot return the old value if the earlier read returns the new one. So in the question there is only one read and we don't really care if this register is regular or atomic. And in this situation it behaves as regular - could be any from two values.

Answer (score 2):

During a concurrent read and write, the read can return either the old value or the new value. To maintain the properties of an atomic register, during the write, there is a point in time:

- before which 33 is always returned, and
- after which 68 is always returned.

Therefore, option (C) is correct.